# create db structure via liquibase and insert mock data from data-h2.sql file

Tags: java, spring, h2, liquibase

Is it possible to setup an environment so that liquibase creates the initial database structure and the spring picks up the mock data from data-h2.sql?

So far in my project liquibase creates the table structure fine, but nothing is picked up from my data-h2.sql file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be an option for you to run `data-h2.sql` from within the liquibase?
So for example something like this

```
<changeSet id="1" author="someone" dbms="h2" context="test">
    <sqlFile path="path/to/your/data-h2.sql" />
</changeSet>
```

note that I've added `dbms="h2"` so it will be executed only on `h2` database and also `context="test"` however you can remove that if you want.

Comment: Awesome! That’s also great!! Thanks